# No such module 'Firebase' error in Xcode 11.0 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I have been looking up on every website that had a similar/identical to this specific issue for Xcode of earlier version errors and I have tried everything and nothing has worked. I have cleaned and then tried to build the project but that hasn't worked.

The terminal shows that the firebase pod has been successfully installed but when try to import firebase the xcode says there is no such module Firebase

[image]

Then I tried to use adding the framework manually but when I try to build then Xcode says framework not found firebasecore .

[image]
[image]

I am stuck there ..what can I do next?

Comment: Can you share the podfile? I had a similar issue and it turned out that the pod has to be added to all targets (including app extensions)

Comment: okay i am adding pod file screen shots

Comment: @ArikSegal thanks definitely the problem was in the pod file. i had add the the pods under "pod for testing" which should have under the "use_frameworks"
thanks for your answer.. I was searching for  every possible solution but checking again in the pod file code thoroughly never cross my mind..  thanks .. was being stuck at for a good amount of time.

Comment: Even I am trying to add manually the firebase, I am also getting 'No such module 'Firebase'' error even though with Xcode 11.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Comment all pods in pod file, then install only

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

For firebase notifications, because some time xcode do not install frameworks of pod files.

Answer (score 0):

Open your pod file from project directory and add this

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

then go to terminal and install pod again

```
pod install
```

after that make sure you build your project (⌘+B) before use.
Make sure you are opening .xcworkspace file from project directory.